# Is an open and closed list essential for a star search.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to make a pathfinding system in Unity that uses a star search algorithm.

My question is, is it possible to implement the algorithm without an open and closed list?

My code currently works in the following way:

- The current node is initially set as the starting node.
- The list of the current node's adjacent nodes is searched and the node with the lowest f cost is returned (calculated using the formulae: f(n) = g(n) + h(n)
- This node with the lowest code is set as the nodeToMoveToNext.
- Current node is set to nodeToMoveToNext.
  Process repeats until currentNode is targetNode.

This code is working, I am able to move to the target goal so why do I need the open and closed list?

Comment: It won't work if you hit a wall and need to turn around...

Answer (score 1):

The closed list can be used to make sure you dont check the same node twice (and step back again). It depends on how you set up your Node structure. Say you define "neighbours" the nodes above, under, left and right of a node.

Node1 has neighbours:

Node2(f=2), Node3(f=10), Node4(f=15) and Node5(f=20).

So you step to Node2.

->Node2 has the following neighbours:

Node5(f=20), Node6(f=24), Node7 (f=30) AND Node1(f=2)

=> you step back to Node1 and do the same over and over.

So it pretty much depends on how you define it for your case. You could also use a bool on each node that says it has already been evaluated for example.

You might want to check

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

and the "Remarks" note after the pseudocode.

Comment: Okay thanks this makes a lot of sense why a closed list is needed.  
Now, with regard to the open list : From what I have read - the open list contains 'The set of currently discovered nodes that are not evaluated yet'. So would i store the adjacent nodes for the current node in the open list?

Comment: Yes, you add them to the open list if they are not in the closed list yet. I would recommend you read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm , understanding how it works first will greatly help you to implement A*.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need lists here because you do not use a star search algorithm.

As for the ability to move to the target goal, it seems to me that that your code does not handle a simple obstacle (dots, 1, and 2 are empty nodes, S is start, G is goal, stars are walls):

```
...S...
..*1*..
..*2*..
..***..
...G...
```

If going only for current node's adjacent nodes, you head right into the dead end and stay there forever going up and down. When you are at position 1, 2 will be the node with the lowest code. When you are at 2, 1 will be. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense, i understand the need for the closed list now. But, I have a follow up question regarding the open list which I posted as a comment on the answer above. Any help is appreciated :)